# Aggregations in JDBCRDD or RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregation, rdd

I'm brand new in Sacla and Spark, and I'm trying to create a SQL query over SqlServer with Spark using jdbcRDD, and do some transformations on it with mappings and aggregations. 
This is what I have, a Table with n String columns and m Number columns.
like

```
"A", "A1",1,2
"A", "A1",4,3
"A", "A2",3,4
"B", "B1",6,7
...
...
```

what i'm looking for is create a hierarchival structure grouping the strings and aggregating the numeric columns like

```
A
|->A1
   |->(5,5)
|->A2
   |->(3,4)
B
|->B1
   |->(6,7)
```

I was able to create the hierarchie but I'm not able to perform the agregation on the list of numeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're loading your data over JDBC I would simply use DataFrames:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame


val options: Map[(String, String)] = ???
val df: DataFrame = sqlContext.read
 .format("jdbc")
 .options(options)
 .load()
 .toDF("k1", "k2", "v1", "v2")

df.printSchema

// root
//  |-- k1: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- k2: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- v1: integer (nullable = true)
//  |-- v2: integer (nullable = true)

df.show

// +---+---+---+---+
// | k1| k2| v1| v2|
// +---+---+---+---+
// |  A| A1|  1|  2|
// |  A| A1|  4|  3|
// |  A| A2|  3|  4|
// |  B| B1|  6|  7|
// +---+---+---+---+
```

With input like above all you need is a basic aggregation

```
df
  .groupBy($"k1", $"k2")
  .agg(sum($"v1").alias("v1"), sum($"v2").alias("v2")).show

// +---+---+---+---+                                                           
// | k1| k2| v1| v2|
// +---+---+---+---+
// |  A| A1|  5|  5|
// |  A| A2|  3|  4|
// |  B| B1|  6|  7|
// +---+---+---+---+
```

If you have RDD like this:

```
val rdd RDD[(String, String, Int, Int)] = ???
rdd.first
// (String, String, Int, Int) = (A,A1,1,2)
```

There is no reason to built complex hierarchy. Simple `PairRDD` should be enough:

```
val aggregated: RDD[((String, String), breeze.linalg.Vector[Int])] = rdd
  .map{case (k1, k2, v1, v2) => ((k1, k2), breeze.linalg.Vector(v1, v2))}
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)

aggregated.first
// ((String, String), breeze.linalg.Vector[Int]) = ((A,A2),DenseVector(3, 4))
```

Keeping hierarchical structure is ineffective but you can group above `RDD` like this:

```
aggregated.map{case ((k1, k2), v) => (k1, (k2, v))}.groupByKey
```

Comment: Great approach, the hierarchical structure is needed by another component, it can be done at last. Question about RDD, Spark execute the same operations to resolve the queries over sources using diferents approachs like DataFrame or JdbcRDD?

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't, but I could be wrong.  DataFrames support for example predicate push-down and I don't think it is an option on `JdbcRDD`. What is most important behind DataFrame API you have an optimizer.